# Question on a symmetric inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b,c $ are positive real number satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc=1$.

How can I prove that $a+b+c\ge \dfrac{3}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let $$a=\cos{A},b=\cos{B},c=\cos{C},A+B+C=\pi$$
because it is known 
$$\cos^2{A}+\cos^2{B}+\cos^2{C}+2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}=1$$

then $$a+b+c=\cos{A}+\cos{B}+\cos{C}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$

Comment: we need to show $\ge$ not $\le ,$ right?

Comment: This must $$a+b+c\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$,

Comment: e.g. $a=1, b=c=0$ has $a+b+c=1<\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Are you using Jensen's inequality, that the mean of the cosine is less than or equal to the cosine of the mean, for A,B,C $\le\frac{\pi}{2}$?